# C: Two Different Arrays Pointing to the Same Struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am working on a problem where I have a "master array" of pointers to a `typedef struct programs`.  For each item/structure that I create, I allocate memory to a `programs* temp` variable and store it into an array `programs* master_array[x]`.

However, my problem requires me to handle errors in the `master_array` where if a `program` goes into a "blocked" state, then I have to manage that(those) process(es) separately.

I want to create a second array called `programs* blocked_array[y]` and store programs that are blocked in there.  In this case, I can have two arrays pointing to the same `program`.  However, when I am finished with handling a `program` in blocked, how can I deallocate it/dereference the `blocked_array[y]`'s pointer to that `program` without impacting the `master_array[x]`'s pointer?

Do I create an empty `program temp`, not allocate memory to this `temp` program and make the `blocked_array[y]` point to that `temp` program to effectively, empty out `blocked_array`?

Would this create some sort of unintended consequence or does doing this stop the blocked array from pointing to it while preserving the `master_array[x]`'s pointer? Any thoughts would help, thanks.

Comment: Have three separate lists: `running`, `runnable`, `blocked`, where each program can only be in *one* of the lists at the same time.

Comment: You can add a `bool isBlocked;` field in your `struct programs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a `bool isBlocked;` field in your `struct programs`, and then you can handle this with a single array by

```
if(master_array[x]->isBlocked)
{
    // Do something
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

Alternatively, you can use another array to store "isBlocked" information:

```
bool isBlocked[sizeof master_array / sizeof master_array[0]] = {0};

...

isBlocked[x] = true;

...

if(isBlocked[x])
{
    // Do something
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: @ sun qingyao  - Thanks qingyao, how would I remove the program from the blocked array when I am finished?  Should I assign something else in its place, i.e. another empty program that isn't allocated any memory?

Comment: @JJL No, don't bother removing the programs. I want to avoid the use of two `array of programs *`, so in either case, there is no `blocked_array[]`